# Does Captain Marvel get her MCU name from Peter Parker?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, spider-man-far-from-home

In the [Spider-Man: Far From Home trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt9L1jCKGnE), Peter Parker references Captain Marvel - and as far as I know, it's the first time in the MCU that the name is mentioned on-screen. In Avengers: Endgame she's never actually called Captain Marvel, only referred to as Carol.

Is there any reason why the name is first mentioned on-screen in a somewhat unrelated movie to Captain Marvel?

Comment: As the film isn't out yet, aren't we supposed to assume that will be revealed then?

Comment: I think it unlikely that Parker would be the one to name her, he has no knowledge of her backstory. We can only assume that in the interim between *Endgame* and *Far From Home* that she's picked a public name.

Comment: @Jenayah Might be the case, I don't expect it though from a spider man movie

Comment: There are 5 years of interactions we don't get to see, plus many years where she was away. She could have adapted the name at any of these times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw the movie today and to answer the question, **no** the movie does not give more about the origins of her superhero name than what's been shown in the trailers.

So apparently some time off-screen, someone established the name for her, but the movie does not go deeper than a just a 'throwaway line'

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: This is only speculation and **not** a definitive answer, as at this point there exists no in-universe explanation on how the name was established.

---

My guess is that everyone in the previous movies knew Carol personally as well as her real name (just like Iron Man was called Tony most of the time from people who knew his name). Also, Carol only returned to earth after Infinity War and was unknown to anyone besides the Avengers for the time to come.

In Endgame, she started to play an actual role towards the end of the movie and showed her face to the world by destroying Thanos ship and fighting alongside everyone. That was the moment people got to "know" her, but not her actual name. So all this lets me assume, that if Peter Parker would refer to her as "Carol", nobody would know who he is talking about, because she is only known to the broader world as "Captain Marvel".

Think of it like the Queen of England. Very many people who that title refers to right now, but by far not so many would know her actual name.

To answer your title question: No, either she chose that name or it was established by the people as her superhero name under which everybody now knows her.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for the movie to come out to might get to see how her name got established

Comment: For a definitive answer yes. At this point it is not possible to give a definitive answer, only guesses

Answer (score 4):

We don't yet know who made up the name but it's pretty clear that the name "Marvel" was inspired by "[Mar-vell](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mar-Vell)". After all, in the comics, the title "Captain Marvel" first belonged to the [Kree man Mar-Vell](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super-Heroes_Vol_1_12).

In the MCU, who knows about Mar-Vell and her connection to Carol?

It doesn’t seem like a story that Peter would know about, since Peter wasn't there during the events of *Captain Marvel*, nor did he spend much time with her while she was on earth seeing as she arrived part of the way into the battle with Thanos, defeated him, stayed for a funeral, then left for space. And in the trailer Peter doesn't even know where she is.

Even the people who were alive during the events of *Endgame* didn't see much of Carol.

Nick Fury, Maria and Monica (?) Rambeau, some of the Kree, some of the Skrulls, and Carol Danvers herself know about Carol's history. And it was definitely Nick Fury's idea to pronounce "Marvel" as a single word, based off this dialogue from *Captain Marvel*, which seems like foreshadowing to me:

> - Nick Fury: You're sure that's what Marvel would want?
> - Carol Danvers: Mar-Vell.
> - NF: That's what I said.
> - CD: It's two words. Mar-Vell.
> - NF: Marvel sounds a lot better. You know, like the Marvelettes? Not ringing any bells?

Of all these characters who definitely know about Carol's backstory, Nick Fury is also the only one we know is also in *Far From Home*.

Comment: If you can offer some citations or resources to back your answer, then it'll make this much more better. (In other media, Carol actually did name herself Marvel after Mar-vell)

Comment: @Vishwa The comics aren't too relevant here because there's always been someone else publicly using the name "Marvel" before Carol. Most of the evidence comes from the MCU itself and because this wasn't clear enough I've expanded on it.

Comment: I was actually referring about the animated series Avengers: Earth's mightiest heroes. Comics are very effin complicated on this Marvel naming shenanigan :). anyway +1 for the answer